# cross sign in android project appearing

Tags: android

I am developing an android application.Its showing no errors in xml or java file.iTS displaying message Your project contains errors.Please fix them before running application
what should i do next.How should i pursue.

Thanks in advance
Tushar sahni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse, look at the Problems view for a description of the problem (Window -> Show View -> Problems). Like @chirag says, sometimes just cleaning your project will clear out strange errors.